# kendo grid with kendo tooltip from an inline template does not work

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template, kendo-tooltip

I have a kendo Grid with tooltip displaying the details in a kendo tooltip. The following template when used as an external template works. However, i am unsure if the template can be passed as an inline template.

Here is my code,
External Template

```
    <script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <ul>
    # for (var i = 0; i < data.applications.length; i++) { #
        <li>#= data.applications[i].name #</li>
    # } #
    </ul>
   </script>
```

and it is called in teh controller as,

```
    $scope.toolTipOptions = {
            filter: "td:nth-child(4)",
            position: "right",
            content: function(e) {
                var grid = e.target.closest(".k-grid").getKendoGrid();
                var dataItem = grid.dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
                var template = kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html());
                return template(dataItem);    
          },
          show: function(e) {
            this.popup.element[0].style.width = "200px";
            this.popup.element[0].style.left = "10px";
          }
    }
```

But when i try to pass an inline template , it complains  that template is not a function. any pointers as to how i could pass an inline template in this case

```
      $scope.toolTipOptions = {
            filter: "td:nth-child(4)",
            position: "right",
            content: function(e) {
                var grid = e.target.closest(".k-grid").getKendoGrid();
                var dataItem = grid.dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));

                var template = "<ul>\# for (var i = 0; i < data.applications.length; i++) { #<li>#= data.applications[i].name #</li>\# } #</ul>"
                return template(dataItem);    
          },
          show: function(e) {
            this.popup.element[0].style.width = "200px";
            this.popup.element[0].style.left = "10px";
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second solution, you probably just need `kendo.template()`. In your code, `template` is defined one line above, as a string.